# Fixed marker and draggable map in MAF jdeveloper

Tags: draggable, marker, oracle-maf

I'm trying to make a draggable map and fixed marker in MAF JDeveloper, but I can't  align the marker to the middle of the map and make the marker get coordinates of this position by clicking the marker.

Here's the sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<amx:view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx"
          xmlns:dvtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx/dvt">
  <amx:panelPage id="pp1">
    <amx:panelStretchLayout id="psl2">
      <amx:facet name="center">
        <dvtm:geographicMap id="geomp1">
          <dvtm:pointDataLayer id="pdl1"/>
        </dvtm:geographicMap>
      </amx:facet>
    </amx:panelStretchLayout>
    <amx:flexLayout id="fl1">
      <dvtm:pointLocation id="pl1">
        <dvtm:marker id="mrk1"/>
      </dvtm:pointLocation>
    </amx:flexLayout>
  </amx:panelPage>
</amx:view>
```

EDIT

I have done the get coordinates part by using MapInputListener but sadly this fires a lot of triggers on the map not just tapping it 
can anyone provide me a better way or how to limit the events to just hold&tap